# How to assign a value entered by the user in a tic tac game?

Tags: python, list

I am working on this not so "cool" version. I will be making it better as I keep working on it.  Here is the code:

```
import random

board=[1,2,3,
       4,5,6,
       7,8,9]

def show_board():
    print('' ,board[0],'|',board[1],'|',board[2],'\n',
          '-----------','\n',
           board[3], '|', board[4], '|', board[5],  '\n',
          '-----------','\n',
          board[6], '|', board[7], '|', board[8]
          )

show_board()

count=0

#winning by value and position - check if x in 3 spots?
def evaluate_line(value,pos1,pos2,pos3):
    if(board[pos1]==value and board[pos2]==value and board[pos3]==value):
        return True

#position combinations for winning value can be x or y
def get_result(value):
    if (evaluate_line(value,0,1,2)):
        return True
    if (evaluate_line(value, 0, 3, 6)):
        return True
    if (evaluate_line(value, 0, 4, 8)):
        return True

# While below is for human player
while True:
    print("select a spot between 1-9 to put an 'x'")
    human=int(input())-1# -1 so that it matches with board not index value

    if(board[human]!='x' and human<=9 and board[human]!='y'):
        board[human]='x'
        count=count+1

        # when count reaches 5 for human means no spot left,get ready to evaluate result
        if (count == 5):
            board[human] = 'x'# useless I thought it will forcefully insert x value
            print('No empty spot left')
            # will check result before break
            if (get_result('x') == True):
                print('Human wins')
            break

        # check result for X-human turn may be human already won
        if (get_result('x') == True):
            print('Human wins')
            break

        #Below is for computer turn AFTER human turn
        while True:
            computer=random.randint(0,len(board)-1)
            if (board[computer] != 'x' and board[computer] != 'y' ):
                board[computer] = 'y'
                break
    else:
        print('That spot s taken')

    show_board()
```

Problem:
For the last x value it is not changing to x since it can't execute the computer's turn(I think).

```
 x | x | x 
 ----------- 
 x | y | y 
 ----------- 
 y | y | 9
```

select a spot between 1-9 to put an 'x'
9
No empty spot left

Question: How can I change that 9 to an x or to be more specific the last remaining spot to x which is currently not getting executed. I tried moving the ==5 break around, but then the computer part was not getting executed.

Comment: There seem to be many things that need to be done and modified in your code. you need more checks for the win, lost and tie. And is the board going to be always this pattern, in the other hand, is it going to be any strategy for the computer to win?

Comment: It's an ongoing task.. all those things you mentioned I will eventually add.Right now I am starting with the simple things. Thank You.

Comment: Are you just not calling `show_board` again after ending the game?